# PHP CURL returns nothing

Tags: php, curl, http-authentication

```
function ParseUrl($URL)
{
    $crl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_PORT, 8086);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "admin:pass");
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    $ret = curl_exec($crl);
    curl_close($crl);
    return $ret;
}

echo ParseUrl('http://xxx.me/serverinfo');
```

The code above simply returns nothing. The page I am trying to get with curl uses http authentication thing.

Am I missing something simple or what?

Comment: If you have any special characters in the username and password (e.g. an `@` symbol if your username is an email address), make sure they're escaped.

Comment: No, username is simply "admin" and password is simple as well.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Start out by doing this and see what you get, and after that it would be pretty obvious what the problem is:

Check if there was an error with the request after curl_exec:

```
if(curl_errno($ch)){
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
```

That will provide you with enough info to know if there was a error with the request. If there was no error, you can check the request sent after curl_exec so you can double check that everything sent is in place:

```
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
```

**Edit: After comments this is what you are looking for what is missing:**

You need to set the option `CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH`.

[Quote from php.net on the subject](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> The HTTP authentication method(s) to
>   use. The options are: CURLAUTH_BASIC,
>   CURLAUTH_DIGEST,
>   CURLAUTH_GSSNEGOTIATE, CURLAUTH_NTLM,
>   CURLAUTH_ANY, and CURLAUTH_ANYSAFE.
>
> The bitwise | (or) operator can be
>   used to combine more than one method.
>   If this is done, cURL will poll the
>   server to see what methods it supports
>   and pick the best one.
>
> CURLAUTH_ANY is an alias for
>   CURLAUTH_BASIC | CURLAUTH_DIGEST |
>   CURLAUTH_GSSNEGOTIATE | CURLAUTH_NTLM.
>
> CURLAUTH_ANYSAFE is an alias for
>   CURLAUTH_DIGEST |
>   CURLAUTH_GSSNEGOTIATE | CURLAUTH_NTLM.

Comment: Curl doesn't return any error but with print_r(curl_getinfo($ch)); i noticed [http_code] => 401 >_< If there a simple way to grab file from a url with http authentication. url format is following "http://admin:pass@xxx.me:8086/serverinfo"

Comment: Also even file_get_contents with full url (with credentials and port) returns 401 Unauthorized. But I can simply navigate to link and browser and it works as it should.

Comment: Thank helped :) I actually realized that I was missing auth option after searching curl 401. But thank you very much, problem solved :)

Comment: Thanks this helped bro.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a space before endpoint definition.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, " https://api.example.com/someAction);
```

So if nothing returns from a curl response, double check the curl options you define before going insane whether the posted json is valid or not.