# CURL returns blank page

Tags: php, curl

i have write this code to get the all data from google but it returns blank. the code is

```
$page = "http://www.google.com";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $page);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$contents = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $contents;
```

can any one find what is wrong in this code?
i have check php info my curl is enabled.

Comment: try [http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php)

Comment: You have a ***PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting '`' in ...*** in your code. Fixing it shows it works fine: http://codepad.viper-7.com/9Yxr7h

Comment: try [PHP CURL returns nothing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324819/php-curl-returns-nothing)

Comment: now i try
if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
 {
  echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
 }
 else
 {
  echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
 }

it returns Curl error: Couldn't resolve host 'www.google.co.in'
what to do now?

Comment: Can you get to www.google.co.in in a web browser? It might be a temporary DNS issue from where YOU are running the code vs where WE are running it

Comment: i have a local linux server. is there any problem with return in local server using CURL?

Answer (score 0):

In my case Google http server's answer contains a redirect to http://www.google.ru/:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.google.ru/
```

Let curl follow this "Location: " header:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```